# Django logging: how do i add logging to django classes and see output in runserver?

Tags: python, django, logging

I want to do some simple printf style debugging to see whats going on in Django's models/base.py.

So in my settings.py I have the 'console' handler wired up to the 'django' logger:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

and in models/base.py I have:

```
    def _save_table(self, raw=False, cls=None, force_insert=False,
                force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
    """
    Does the heavy-lifting involved in saving. Updates or inserts the data
    for a single table.
    """
    logging.debug("IN SAVE TABLE")
```

But when I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

while I see debug output from django, I don't see the line I just added.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience we need to declare which logger we use, so given this - the following should work:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('django')
logger.error('error')
logger.info('info')
logger.debug('debug')
```